# Angular page not loading from top after navigation angular material

Tags: angular-material, angular-ui-router

I am using angular material, I am scrolling page to middle and  navigating from one component to another one but after navigation page not loading from top it is showing in middle. Could any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, hope it helps
add this in your AppComponent

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';
```

and

```
constructor(private router: Router){
 //subscribes every changes of your route
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
   if (event instanceof NavigationEnd){
      //scroll to top
      window.scrollTo(0,0);`enter code here`
   }
});
}
```